# Organization Browser web part - how to display employee's position under his name?

Tags: organization-browser

Everywhere I see Organization Browser web part on the web, there are always job titles under people names, like here:
[image]

On our company's sharepoint a single contact on organization browser is displayed with photo ONLY. I've already found out that if I fill "About Me" field, then this text will appear on my contact. But how to make job title visible below the name? Is it dependent on Sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1):

As I know it is not possible to customize out of the box Organization Browsers this way.

You may look at 3rd party web parts. They allow to customize visual representation of the Org Chart.

This one is developed by my team:
[Plumsail SharePoint Org Chart](http://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart/)

This one is alternative:
[TeamImprover Org Chart](http://sharepointorgchart.com/)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to do some coding. Hope these can help you get started:

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/11/customize-my-profile-tabs-for.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spsocial/archive/2010/04/08/customizing-my-sites-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://nextconnect.blogspot.com/2010/09/disabling-whats-happening-display-on.html

Comment: i was asking about organization browser web part that is done in silverlight - no html extra coding can help me with this. I am not itnerested in customizing the whole site.